# Disable Hyperlinks inside TextFields from opening web browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hyperlink, textfield

In Flash, I have a TextField with hyperlinks with the ["event:" prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041642/1294758). This triggers the link clicked event, within which I'm reading the event ID code and responding accordingly.

The problem is everytime a link is clicked, the web browser opens with the same link. How do I disable the web browser from opening?

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()` in your `link` handler?

Comment: In that link you showed was **[this part](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12041631/2057709)** not enough to do what you want..? Capturing links with `TextEvent.LINK` and running an internal AS3 function instead.

Comment: @Brain - Due to some complications I was unable to do that. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: @VC.One - I'm doing a variation of that, yes. But since I'm in AIR Flash opens a web browser as well. I'll try `preventDefault()` or something like that and let you know.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I finally found the answer after extended debugging. My conclusions are listed in my answer below. Vote it up if it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR version:

The ONLY reason the web browser will pop open, whether in Flash Player or in AIR, is that you forgot to add `event:` to the start of your anchor href.

### The full explanation:

You do NOT need to use `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the web browser from opening. In fact you do not even need to subscribe to the `TextEvent.LINK` event at all. All you need to do is ensure you are adding `event:` as a prefix to your anchor tag's href.

After extended debugging, I discovered that **only the href is responsible** for either of these happening:

**Behavior 1** - Your href has the `event:` prefix

- The web browser does NOT open in any circumstance.
- If you have subscribed to the `TextEvent.LINK` event, it'll be fired the moment the user clicks the link. If not, nothing happens.
- The `TextEvent.LINK` event can be added to any parent DisplayObject, such as the parent Sprite, or even the Stage. It does not need to be specifically added to the TextField in question.

**Behavior 2** - Your href has no `event:` prefix

- The `TextEvent.LINK` does not fire when such links are clicked. So it can't be used to prevent the web browser from opening.
- The web browser opens / handles the link href based on the `target` property.
- If `target` is `_self` and you are already in a web browser (with Flash Player) then the same window/tab is reused to open the link. If you are in AIR then the default web browser pops open with the link.

Comment: Good stuff, very useful to share this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.. You can differentiate links by using a Switch/Case statement or if easier then just use multiple If/Else statements..

```
myTextField.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, linkClickHandler);

function linkClickHandler(evt:TextEvent):void 
{
    trace("## clicked text is: " + evt.text);

    if (evt.text == "what_you_want")
    {
        var url_1 : String = "http://www.example_A.com/";
        var request_1 : URLRequest = new URLRequest( url_1 );
        navigateToURL( request_1, '_blank' );
    }

    if (evt.text == "something_else")
    {
        var url_2 : String = "http://www.example_B.com/";
        var request_2 : URLRequest = new URLRequest( url_2 );
        navigateToURL( request_2, '_blank' );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats nice, but I want exactly the opposite. I'm already handling the link and reading the `evt.text`, I know that. The problem is Flash automatically opens the web browser to whatever is in my link text. I DONT want the web browser to open.

Comment: But the problem arises, that when I click play or pause, Flash opens a web browser in addition! I don't want the web browser to open because I have already responded to the link in my app itself!

Comment: I'm in Adobe AIR, if that matters, not Flash Player in the browser.